# Contest: ask questions, earn badges, win prizes!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

Let's ask more questions!  More questions will allow more answers, and good, answered questions make our site even more awesome.  More good questions can also help in our quest to graduate.  Plus, asking and answering more questions can earn you valuable reputation points and badges!

While we're asking more questions, let's try to fill out some of our under-served tags.  Did you know that when our top 40 tags each have 200 questions, people can earn the Generalist badge?  This is kind of a site milestone (not just about individuals earning badges) -- can we do it?  Let's find out!

### Contest Rules

Here's how it will work:

1. From now until the end of **March 23** UTC (that's 30 days), you earn one point each time you ask a question that:

   - uses a tag that has at least 10 and fewer than 200 questions ([full tag list](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tags)), and
   - has a score of at least +1, and
   - is open at the end of the contest
2. You get one point per qualifying *question*, regardless of how many tags it uses.  You can use tags as often as you like.
3. Tags are an ever-moving target (and some curation is happening).  If a question qualified at the time you asked it, that's good enough -- we will not yank points out from under you with housekeeping retaggings.
4. However, if you add a clearly-bogus tag just to get a contest entry, judges reserve the right to disqualify a question.  This rule is here for rules lawyers, not because I think it likely that our community members are going to game this.
5. We probably haven't anticipated all wrinkles that might come up.  We reserve the right to modify the rules during the contest if need be.  Our goal is to be reasonable and, within that, err on the side of giving points -- we're here to have fun together and help our site.

We're setting a minimum of 10 questions on a tag because we've got some noise down at the very bottom of the tag list, and so that new tags get some vetting from the community before they count for contest entries.

### Mechanics

**Please record all entries by the end of Sunday, March 24 UTC so I can post a final tally.**  (They still need to have qualified by the deadline, but I can't assume you'll jump over here immediately to add them, hence this buffer space.)

When you have a new question with qualifying score, edit the community-wiki answer here with your name, a link to the question, and the tag(s) you're invoking.  (You only need one tag, but feel free to list all that qualify so we can all see where we're building.)

If you don't have enough reputation to edit the answer, leave a comment on the answer with the information and someone will edit it in for you.

If you see an entry you think doesn't qualify, leave a comment on the answer explaining the problem.

### Prizes

What do you get?  More good questions for the site!  Bragging rights!

Ok, I also have some prizes. :-)

Stack Exchange has donated some swag (thanks!), so in addition to those other benefits, we'll award physical prizes to:

- the top three point-getters
- *and* some randomly-selected entrants with at least three points

(To claim a swag prize, you must be willing to privately share a shipping address that will be deleted as soon as your package is in the mail.)

The very *best* prize, of course, would be for Writing to graduate, but that isn't under our control.  Nice notebooks, though, I can send you!  And some pens looted from another site, because all of *our* users are super, too!  And there just might be some other things in your box too -- we'll see!

[image: swag]

---

**For the winners and wrap-up, see [this announcement](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1917/1993).**

Comment: I got a question about this, so in case anybody else is also wondering: the question needs to be open at the end of the contest; it doesn't have to stay continuously open.  If you ask a question, it gets put on hold, you fix it, and it gets reopened, that's *fine*.  The goal is good questions for the site, which might involve some bumps along the way.  We're not going to penalize people for a question not being perfect in the first version.

Comment: Small cheat: One of my tags on my most recent question has 10 questions asked because mine was the 10th.  But there are other qualifying tags.  Full disclosure :-D

Comment: This contest seems to be working. Our questions per day has been trending upward since it started.

Comment: @linksassin agreed.  Some really great questions too. I was afraid the contest might increase the amount of questions for questions' sake but, in general, that hasn't happened. I'm finding too that 1) I'm getting much better at asking questions and 2) even though I've put up legit questions, they weren't things I was necessarily needing input on, but it turns out the input has been really useful and I'm incorporating some of it into my book.  Win-win all around!

Comment: We're really pumping up the question-per-day score on Area-51. Hopefully we will be able to push it to promotion-status.

Comment: What happens in the case of ties? For example, at the moment Cyn, Liquid and I are all tied for 2nd place. If it were two of us, it would have been fine. But there's 3 of us, and bruglesco in 1st.

Comment: @Galastel we'll resolve ties in the direction of being more generous, don't worry.

Comment: I checked all of the questions that are below me on the entry list, with no closures.

Comment: @bruglesco thank you!  I just checked the rest (also no closures).

Comment: Not just closures!  Some of the questions listed may not have 1+ points.  While it may be hard to judge the timing of that, in most cases it's pretty clear.  Also to check if there is at least one tag with the right number of questions on it (with allowances for changes over time...like anything that went over 200 during the contest still counts).

Comment: @Cyn I was checking tags as they came in, but you're right -- I didn't check scores.  (Update: have checked; disqualified one entry after checking its vote history.)

Comment: I just went through them all.  327 questions!!  I did not open any questions, only looked at the question list.  I also found the disqualified question (no downvotes or upvotes so this was not a case of it qualifying then losing it).  While some people reported all their tags even if they didn't qualify, every question on the contest list did have at least 1 qualifying tag.  I did not bother to write down questions that would have qualified for the contest if only the authors chose to enter. BUT I did find two authors who did enter the contest but left out questions  I'll put them down below.

Comment: @April listed 3 questions in the contest but also had 3 qualifying ones not in the list: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43927/how-much-character-growth-crosses-the-line-into-breaking-the-character and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/content-sites-any-still-around-and-useful and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42664/self-publishing-nonfiction-help-guides-on-amazon

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi listed 2 questions in the contest but also had 2 qualifying ones not in the list: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43698/is-it-advisable-to-write-a-teaser-for-your-blog-posts and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43691/how-to-collect-scattered-ideas-on-various-topics-in-to-a-blog-post-writing-arti

Comment: Checking people's self-counts in the question list.  They are all fine except as discussed above.

Comment: @Cyn thanks!  I just noticed and added Prasad's but hadn't seen April's yet.

Comment: @Cyn if you're still here, could you check if imatowrite is under-reported?  Looks like there are a few more in this timeframe but I haven't checked tags and scores.

Comment: I checked everyone.  Those two were the only underreported folks.  (It is possible I missed one, but I did check.) *BUT* there were several people who had questions they did not enter because they didn't have any qualifying tags.  It wouldn't be hard in almost all cases to add in legit and useful tags for each of them in the 10-200 question range (since there are so many), but I figured that wasn't my job at this point.

Comment: @Cyn thanks; I'd missed your earlier comment where you checked *all* the new questions.  Thanks for all the help!  I'm sorry some people with qualifying questions didn't participate, but I saw a lot of "hey, we've got this contest" comments along the way and the post was featured all month, so I don't think it's up to us to also hunt them down.  Some people just aren't into contests, after all.  I *really* appreciate all the help!

Comment: Our question count went way up.  Up a lot more than the reported questions here.  So people may have been mindful of the contest, even if they didn't choose to enter.  Or they may have just seen more activity and decided to add to it.  Some of the questions were .... umm, let's say subpar but I'm not sure there were proportionately more of those than usual.

Comment: Thanks Cyn!  I know last Friday I added one that I should have put here, but I was too busy at work.  I guess I forgot about a few others.

Answer (score 5):

### Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

- Username, [tag](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag), *link to question*

Or, when you have more than one entry (which I hope lots of people will), use sub-lists (follow Cyn's lead).

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

- Cyn (20)

  - [screenwriting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenwriting)[planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) [Why write a book when there's a movie in my head?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42405/why-write-a-book-when-theres-a-movie-in-my-head)
  - [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing)[business-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-writing)[book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) [Materials to promote my book in person](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42485/materials-to-promote-my-book-in-person)
  - [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)[genre](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre) [Is time travel science fiction or fantasy?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42527/is-time-travel-science-fiction-or-fantasy)
  - [young-adult](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult)[theme](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme)[middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade) [Crossing the line from Middle-Grade to Young-Adult](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42582/crossing-the-line-from-middle-grade-to-young-adult)
  - [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)[language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)[lyrics](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyrics)[middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade) [What language shall they sing in?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42634/what-language-shall-they-sing-in)
  - [narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative)[showing-telling](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showing-telling)[child-characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-characters)[emotions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotions) [Making him into a bully (how to show mild violence)](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42706/making-him-into-a-bully-how-to-show-mild-violence)
  - [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)[middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade)[historical-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-fiction) [Incorporating research and background: How much is too much?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42752/incorporating-research-and-background-how-much-is-too-much)
  - [book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book)[research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)[blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog)[historical-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-fiction) [Should I write a companion book/blog?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42823/should-i-write-a-companion-book-blog)
  - [publisher](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publisher)[psychology-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology-of-writing) [Publishers that drag their feet](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42892/publishers-that-drag-their-feet/42893#42893)
  - [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming)[pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov)[narrator](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator)[middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade) [Naming things the POV character doesn't know](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42942/naming-things-the-pov-character-doesnt-know)
  - [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)[tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) [Mariner Software for writers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42991/mariner-software-for-writers?noredirect=1#comment70554_42991)
  - [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)[language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)[child-characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-characters) [Showing the transition of language comprehension change](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43047/showing-the-transition-of-language-comprehension-change)
  - [submitting-work](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/submitting-work)[chapters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chapters) [What to submit when asked for "sample chapters"?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43406/what-to-submit-when-asked-for-sample-chapters)
  - [education](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) [Is it necessary to take writing classes and learn formal fiction structure?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43471/is-it-necessary-to-take-writing-classes-and-learn-formal-fiction-structure)
  - [voice](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice) [Writing in a Christian voice](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43669/writing-in-a-christian-voice)
  - [story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story)[symbolism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) [Symbolism of 18 Journeyers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43725/symbolism-of-18-journeyers)
  - [child-characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-characters)[middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade)[historical-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-fiction) [Showing mass murder in a kid's book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43773/showing-mass-murder-in-a-kids-book)
  - [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction)[blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog)[organization](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organization)[chapters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chapters) [Organizing categories and tags for a writing blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43955/organizing-categories-and-tags-for-a-writing-blog)
  - [young-adult](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult)[middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade) [Is there a market for all-ages novels?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43954/is-there-a-market-for-all-ages-novels)
  - [career](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career)[writing-groups](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-groups) [Should I join writers organizations?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43974/should-i-join-writers-organizations)
- Liquid (18),

  - [genre](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre),[tropes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes) [How do I avoid the "chosen hero" feeling?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42422/how-do-i-avoid-the-chosen-hero-feeling)
  - [genre](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre),[horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror),[symbolism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism),[technique](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) [Monsters of psychological horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42748/monsters-of-psychological-horror)
  - [genre](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre),[fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy),[theme](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme),[world-building](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building) [Fictional races and fictional racism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42775/fictional-races-and-fictional-racism)
  - [world-building](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building),[creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing) [How many elements can you focus on during worldbuilding?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42913/how-many-elements-can-you-focus-on-during-worldbuilding)
  - [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing),[blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog),[social-media](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media),[website](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) [Should an author include user-interactive sections in his website?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42917/what-are-the-must-have-for-an-author-website)
  - [conventions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conventions),[creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[style](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) [Are paired adjectives bad style?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/are-paired-adjectives-bad-style)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing),[short-story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story),[genre](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre),[theme](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme)  [What should tie a collection of short-stories together?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43556/what-should-tie-a-collection-of-short-stories-together)
  - [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing),[citation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation),[software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation),[documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) [How to include external references when writing internal documentation?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43557/how-to-include-external-references-when-writing-internal-documentation)
  - [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing),[resume](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) [Personal or impersonal in a technical resume](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43820/personal-or-impersonal-in-a-technical-resume)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters),[novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel),[pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov),[reader-engagement](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reader-engagement) [Does the reader need to like the PoV character?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43843/does-the-reader-need-to-like-the-pov-character)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters),[novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel),[humor](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor) [How can I write humor as character trait?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43858/how-can-i-write-humor-as-character-trait)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[technique](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique),[description](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/description),[metaphor](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphor),[figures-of-speech](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures-of-speech) [When is using a simile better than giving a literal description?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43866/when-is-using-a-simile-better-than-giving-a-literal-description)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[exercises](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises),[contests](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contests) [Are friendly writing contests a useful exercise?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43893/are-friendly-writing-contests-a-useful-exercise)
  - [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror),[emotions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotions) [Can disgust be a key component of horror?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43911/can-disgust-be-a-key-component-of-horror)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel),[structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure),[sequel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequel),[3-acts](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3-acts) [Introducing a character in the third act?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43921/introducing-a-character-in-the-third-act)
  - [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction),[constructed-language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructed-language),[cryptography](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) [Using substitution ciphers to generate new alphabets in a novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43936/using-substitution-ciphers-to-generate-new-alphabeths-in-a-novel)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel),[structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure),[pacing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacing),[3-acts](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3-acts) <s>[The three acts and their relative length](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43940/the-three-acts-and-their-relative-length)</s> (score 0)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters),[science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction),[pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov) [Characterizing a sentient robot: inhuman PoV](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43942/characterizing-a-sentient-robot-inhuman-pov)
  - [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing),[novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel),[science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction),[pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov)  [Characterizing a sentient robot: sensory data](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43941/characterizing-a-sentient-robot-sensory-data)
- Mithrandir, [young-adult](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult), [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author), [setting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setting): [When writing in a school context without ever having been to school, how do I make sure that my story is accurate within school context?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42406/)
- Spectrosaurus, [historical-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-fiction), [narrator](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator), [voice](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice): [Is it possible to narrate a novel in a faux-historical style without alienating the reader?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42464/is-it-possible-to-narrate-a-novel-in-a-faux-historical-style-without-alienating)
- April (6)

  - [script](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script), [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction), [podcast](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podcast): [Podcast Script - Recurring Elements](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42478/podcast-script-recurring-elements)
  - [script](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script), [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction), [humor](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor), [podcast](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podcast): 
    [Examples & humor in educational podcast](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42486/examples-humor-in-educational-podcast)
  - [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning), [websites](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites),[creative-commons](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-commons): [Can we "borrow" our answers to populate our own websites?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42608/can-we-borrow-our-answers-to-populate-our-own-websites)
  - [pacing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacing) [How much character growth crosses the line into breaking the character](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43927/how-much-character-growth-crosses-the-line-into-breaking-the-character)
  - [websites](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites) [time-management](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-management) [Content Sites - any still around and useful?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/content-sites-any-still-around-and-useful)
  - [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction) [Self-publishing Nonfiction Help Guides on Amazon?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42664/self-publishing-nonfiction-help-guides-on-amazon)
- motosubatsu, [openings](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings), [third-person](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/third-person):[Using a different POV just for the opening line](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42483/using-a-different-pov-just-for-the-opening-line)
- F1Krazy, [exposition](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exposition), [protagonist](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protagonist): [Protagonist constantly has to have long words explained to her. Will this get tedious?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42470/23927)
- Galastel (21)

  - [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)[setting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setting)[realism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism): [Finding out about other countries' military day-to-day](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42456/14704)
  - [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), [Showing friendship between people of different ranks - maintain formality, or drop it?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42541/14704)
  - [playwriting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playwriting)[planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning), [What are the meta considerations when writing a play?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42605/14704)
  - [audience](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience), [How does one write from a minority culture? A question on cultural references](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42655/14704)
  - [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)[first-time-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-time-author), [Consulting experts - why should they talk to someone who isn't a published writer yet?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42690/14704)
  - [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software), [Coloured comments in a text editor - is it possible?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42725/14704)
  - [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming), [Every character has a name](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42782/14704)
  - [narrator](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator), [Everyone is beautiful](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42863/14704)
  - [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)[worldbuilding](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding), [Map-making software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42929/14704)
  - [symbolism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism), [Sometimes a banana is just a banana](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42938/14704)
  - [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming)[narrator](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator), [What should the omniscient narrator call a character?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43056/14704)
  - [punctuation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation), [End-of-line hyphenation - how should it be used?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43096/14704)
  - [audience](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience), [How do I write for the majority, without alienating my minority?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43151/14704)
  - [story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story), [Help! My Character is too much for her story!](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43181/14704)
  - [openings](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings), [How to open a serious speech?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43469/14704)
  - [story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story)[middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade), [Mortal danger in mid-grade literature](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43687)
  - [pacing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacing)[3-act](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3-act), [Turning away from the 3-act structure - what guides my pacing now?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43939/14704)
  - [scene](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene)[pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov), [Pre-modern battle - command it, or fight in it?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43961/14704)
  - [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction), [Future battlegrounds](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43959/14704)
  - [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), [Famous mistranslations - correct them?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43968/14704)
  - [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)[quotes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes)[figures-of-speech](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures-of-speech), [When does a phrase change from “quote” to “expression coined by”?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43962/14704)
- bruglesco (23)

  - [videogame](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/videogame), [Ways to develop characters in a fast paced video game](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42542/ways-to-develop-characters-in-a-fast-paced-video-game)
  - [software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation), [Strategies for writing software design documents](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42548/strategies-for-writing-software-design-documents)
  - [software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation)[criticism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism)[feedback](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback), [Methods for writing a code review](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42639/methods-for-writing-a-code-review)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process), [How to write a Stack Exchange comment?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42641/how-to-write-a-stack-exchange-comment)
  - [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry)[criticism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism)[feedback](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback), [What to look for when criticizing poetry?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42695/what-to-look-for-when-criticizing-poetry)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process), [Injecting creativity into a cookbook](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42760/injecting-creativity-into-a-cookbook)
  - [feedback](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback)[criticism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism), [What is in scope for criticizing technical writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42841/what-is-in-scope-for-criticizing-technical-writing)
  - [writers-block](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writers-block)[process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process)[discipline](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline)[time-management](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-management), [What are some techniques to avoid digital distraction?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42839/what-are-some-techniques-to-avoid-digital-distraction)
  - [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning)[artwork](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artwork), [Knowing when to use pictures over words](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42857/knowing-when-to-use-pictures-over-words)
  - [criticism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism)[feedback](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback), [Approaches to criticizing short fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42875/approaches-to-criticizing-short-fiction)
  - [criticism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism)[feedback](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback), [Criticizing long fiction. How is it different from short?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42915/criticizing-long-fiction-how-is-it-different-from-short)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process), [How to write a Stack Exchange Question?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/how-to-write-a-stack-exchange-question)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process)[prose](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prose), [Writing effectively under very brief constraints](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42925/writing-effectively-under-very-brief-constraints)
  - [sentence-structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure)[rhythm](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhythm)[emotions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotions), [Using rhythm to evoke emotion](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42993/using-rhythm-to-evoke-emotion)
  - [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)[tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools)[poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), [Scansion tool for checking my meter](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43000/scansion-tool-for-checking-my-meter)
  - [twist](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twist), [Too soon for a plot twist?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43167/too-soon-for-a-plot-twist)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process)[videogame](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/videogame)[software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation), [Documenting story in a videogame](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43226/documenting-story-in-a-videogame)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process)[writers-block](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writers-block), [Avoiding burnout](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43274/avoiding-burnout)
  - [software-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-documentation), [Documenting software requirements](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43477/documenting-software-requirements)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process)[rules](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules), [Rules about breaking the rules. How do I do it well?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43508/rules-about-breaking-the-rules-how-do-i-do-it-well)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process), [When must a character grow beyond their archetype?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43902/when-must-a-character-grow-beyond-their-archetype)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process)[theme](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme), [Does success imply validation and agreement?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43906/does-success-imply-validation-and-agreement)
  - [process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process)[showing-telling](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showing-telling), [Delivering sarcasm](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43972/delivering-sarcasm)
- linksassin (4)

  - [plagiarism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagiarism), [Can I write a book of my D&D game?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42734/can-i-write-a-book-of-my-dd-game)
  - [readers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readers)[process](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process), [Write for an audience or find an audience for your writing?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42731/write-for-an-audience-or-find-an-audience-for-your-writing/42746#42746)
  - [writers-block](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writers-block), [How to write exciting updates?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42790/how-to-write-exciting-updates)
  - [beta-readers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-readers)[feedback](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback), [Should beta-readers have genre experience?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43008/33442)
- Karan Desai (3)

  - [clarity](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarity), [How to write a puzzle without being too descriptive or vague?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42900/how-to-write-a-puzzle-without-being-too-descriptive-or-vague)
  - [self-publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-publishing)[blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog),[What exactly is the difference between Wordpress.org and Wordpress.com and what should be used for self publishing?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43173/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-wordpress-org-and-wordpress-com-and-what)
  - [style](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style)[marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing),[How to make readers know that my work has used a hidden constraint?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43436/how-to-make-readers-know-that-my-work-has-used-a-hidden-constraint#)
- celtschk, [foreshadowing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreshadowing), [What is a good way to foreshadow that magic is actually very advanced technology?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42849/what-is-a-good-way-to-foreshadow-that-magic-is-actually-very-advanced-technology)
- Secespitus (3)

  - [videogame](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/videogame) [wordcount](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordcount) [branching-narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/branching-narrative)  [How many words do visual novels contain on average per hour of gameplay?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43271/23159)
  - [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) [novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) [How much does translating a novel cost?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43288/23159)
  - [sales](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sales) [international](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) [In which countries do printed fantasy novels sell the most?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43339/23159)
- Prasad_Joshi (4)

  - [blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) [morality](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality) [Do I need to convey a moral for each of my blog posts?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43694/23159)
  - [blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) [What should be the ideal length of sentences in a blog post for ease of reading?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43752/what-should-be-the-ideal-length-of-sentences-in-a-blog-post-for-ease-of-reading)
  - [blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) [Is it advisable to write a teaser for your blog posts?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43698/1993)
  - [blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) [How to collect scattered ideas on various topics in to a blog post/ writing article?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43691/1993)
- Monica Cellio (not entering because I'm running the contest, but for tracking):

  - [blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) [artwork](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artwork) [How large should photos on my blog be?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42923/how-large-should-photos-on-my-blog-be)
  - [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) [How can I highlight changes in HTML output from Flare, based on branch diff?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43673/how-can-i-highlight-changes-in-html-output-from-flare-based-on-branch-diff) .
- [imatowrite](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/37111/) (10)

  - [websites](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites) [career](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) [When should a starting writer get his own webpage?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43687)
  - [outline](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outline) [brainstorming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainstorming) [How specific should I get when brainstorming with what-if exercise?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43617)
  - [criticism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism) [reviews](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reviews) [Is there a crowd-sourced site for reviews and critique?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43597)
  - [fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction) [structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) [chapters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chapters)  [Is there a place for an epilogue in a standalone novel?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43788)
  - [proofreading](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofreading) [first-draft](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-draft) [beta-readers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-readers)  [Should I show the plot to my beta reader?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43686)
  - [characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) [plot](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) [realism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism)  [Would it be believable to defy demographics in a story?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43678)
  - [technique](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) [middle-grade](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-grade) [profanity](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profanity)  [How to write cleanly even if my character uses expletive language?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43540)
  - [editing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing) [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) [ulysses](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ulysses) [How to do a global find and replace in Ulysses](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43444)
  - [dialogue](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) [resources](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) [historical-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-fiction) [Dialect resources for early/mid 20th Century Midwestern American speech](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43291)
  - [pseudonym](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudonym) [career](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) [Should I create a domain name using a pen name that is common with another person's domain name?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43835)
- Shokhet:

  - [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) [Best practice for academic writing: write and cite or write first?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43719/best-practice-for-academic-writing-write-and-cite-or-write-first)

Comment: @April go ahead and add questions when they meet the other criteria even if you think they might get closed.  If they're closed they might be reopened, after all.  We'll do a check for closed questions at the end of the contest, but we're not trying to track fluctuations in the meantime.

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi done.  You now have over 100 rep, so you should be able to edit in future entries yourself.

Comment: @Shokhet, looks like your edit broke the formatting.  I'm going to roll back and re-add your entry.